# Developing Office Add-in, Need Fallback for AppsForOffice CDN

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, cdn, fallback

I am finalizing the JS and CSS loading for an Office add-in, and need to write a fallback for the Office CDN. I have one for jQuery that works, but I don't know what to check for if the AppsForOffice files do not load. What object do I need to test for? I've searches around and did not find any example code for this CDN.

jQuery Example (does work)

```
<!-- jQuery CDN and fallback -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

AppsForOffice Example (does not work)

```
<!-- Office CDN and fallback -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com">
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.6.1/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.6.1/fabric.components.min.css">
<script>
    window.Office ||
        document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js">\x3C/script>')
    document.write('<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../../Content/fabric.min.css" />')
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.components.min.css" />')
</script>
```

As mentioned, what object do I need to test for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is `window.OSF` (or just `OSF`). This can be determined by examining `office.js`.

You'll also need to change the code from:

```
window.Office ||
document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js">\x3C/script>')
document.write('<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../../Content/fabric.min.css" />')
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.components.min.css" />')
```

to something like:

```
if(!window.OSF) {
    document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js">\x3C/script>');
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.min.css" />');
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.components.min.css" />');
}
```

in order for the fallback to function as intended.

Comment: I tried something similar,  window.OSF || , but it did not work. I will try your version

Comment: The suggested code is correct, as was my own attempt, but my local office.js was outdated. Once updated to the same as the CDN, it worked correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately I used your suggested logic, with modification.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the .js library I was calling, and saw that instead of Office, the file is returning an OSF object, so changed the fallback code as follows. Verified in Chrome's audit function.

This is using the answer from Ouroborus, with modification to load all the pieces required by Office, as well as code to detect the difference between web and desktop. Depending on your needs, you will likely need to load a different language pack, or different web/win32 version.

```
<!--
    Office CDN and fallback
    CSS and JS are copies of referenced CDN's
    If the CDN's change, the fallbacks must change'
-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com">
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.OSF) {
        document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js">\x3C/script>');

        if (location.search === "?et=") {
            document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/outlook-web-16.01.js">\x3C/script>');
        } else {
            document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/outlook-win32-16.01.js">\x3C/script>');
        }

        document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/en-us/office_strings.js">\x3C/script>');
        document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/en-us/outlook_strings.js">\x3C/script>');
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.min.2.6.1.css" type="text/css" />');
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/fabric.components.2.6.1.min.css" type="text/css"  />');
        document.write('<script src="../../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js">\x3C/script>');
    } else {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.6.1/fabric.min.css" />');
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.6.1/fabric.components.min.css" />');
    }
</script>
```

Leaving here to assist anyone else that might have a similar question.

Comment: Your `<link>` fallbacks will always be loaded with that code.